# Node.js redis "unknown command 'hset'"?

Tags: node.js, redis, v8, node-redis

I'm new to redis, and I'm trying out various examples. However, it doesn't seem to work:

```
root@localhost:~# node lol.js
Reply: OK
Error: Error: Error: ERR unknown command 'hset'
Error: Error: Error: ERR unknown command 'hset'

/root/node_modules/redis/index.js:468
                throw callback_err;
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Command.callback (/root/lol.js:15:28)
    at RedisClient.return_error (/root/node_modules/redis/index.js:464:25)
    at HiredisReplyParser.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/redis/index.js:253:14)
    at HiredisReplyParser.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at HiredisReplyParser.execute (/root/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/hiredis.js:41:18)
    at RedisClient.on_data (/root/node_modules/redis/index.js:440:27)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/redis/index.js:70:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:367:14)
```

I'm using one of the example scripts on the github page for node-redis. I'm on Debian Squeeze.

Comment: What is your Redis server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is not with your code (of course it could recognize the error sent by the server) or with the node redis module but with the Redis server.

You need to upgrade it to a newer version, [`HSET`](http://redis.io/commands/hset) command is supported since version 2.0.0.

Comment: How do I check what version it is? I used `apt-get install redis-server`.

Comment: Start the `redis-cli` and type `INFO`, or you can check the package version with `dpkg -l redis-server`

Comment: Somewhat simpler way to get version using redis-cli: `redis-cli info | grep version`.